# Istio direct Pod to Pod communication

Tags: kubernetes, istio

I have a problem with the communication to a Pod from a Pod deployed with Istio? I actually need it to [make Hazelcast discovery working with Istio](https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast-kubernetes/issues/118), but I'll try to generalize the issue here.

Let's have a sample hello world service deployed on Kubernetes. The service replies to the HTTP request on the port 8000.

```
$ kubectl create deployment nginx --image=crccheck/hello-world
```

The created Pod has an internal IP assigned:

```
$ kubectl get pods -o wide
NAME                               READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE   IP           NODE                                                  NOMINATED NODE
hello-deployment-84d876dfd-s6r5w   1/1     Running   0          8m    10.20.3.32   gke-rafal-test-istio-1-0-default-pool-91f437a3-cf5d   <none>
```

In the job `curl.yaml`, we can use the Pod IP directly.

```
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: Job
metadata:
  name: curl
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: curl
        image: byrnedo/alpine-curl
        command: ["curl",  "10.20.3.32:8000"]
      restartPolicy: Never
  backoffLimit: 4
```

Running the job without Istio works fine.

```
$ kubectl apply -f curl.yaml
$ kubectl logs pod/curl-pptlm
...
Hello World
...
```

However, when I try to do the same with Istio, it does not work. The HTTP request gets blocked by Envoy.

```
$ kubectl apply -f <(istioctl kube-inject -f curl.yaml)
$ kubectl logs pod/curl-s2bj6 curl
...
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 10.20.3.32 port 8000: Connection refused
```

I've played with Service Entries, MESH_INTERNAL, and MESH_EXTERNAL, but with no success. How to bypass Envoy and make a direct call to a Pod?

---

EDIT: The output of `istioctl kube-inject -f curl.yaml`.

```
$ istioctl kube-inject -f curl.yaml
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: Job
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: null
  name: curl
spec:
  backoffLimit: 4
  template:
    metadata:
      annotations:
        sidecar.istio.io/status: '{"version":"dbf2d95ff300e5043b4032ed912ac004974947cdd058b08bade744c15916ba6a","initContainers":["istio-init"],"containers":["istio-proxy"],"volumes":["istio-envoy","istio-certs"],"imagePullSecrets":null}'
      creationTimestamp: null
    spec:
      containers:
      - command:
        - curl
        - 10.16.2.34:8000/
        image: byrnedo/alpine-curl
        name: curl
        resources: {}
      - args:
        - proxy
        - sidecar
        - --domain
        - $(POD_NAMESPACE).svc.cluster.local
        - --configPath
        - /etc/istio/proxy
        - --binaryPath
        - /usr/local/bin/envoy
        - --serviceCluster
        - curl.default
        - --drainDuration
        - 45s
        - --parentShutdownDuration
        - 1m0s
        - --discoveryAddress
        - istio-pilot.istio-system:15010
        - --zipkinAddress
        - zipkin.istio-system:9411
        - --connectTimeout
        - 10s
        - --proxyAdminPort
        - "15000"
        - --concurrency
        - "2"
        - --controlPlaneAuthPolicy
        - NONE
        - --statusPort
        - "15020"
        - --applicationPorts
        - ""
        env:
        - name: POD_NAME
          valueFrom:
            fieldRef:
              fieldPath: metadata.name
        - name: POD_NAMESPACE
          valueFrom:
            fieldRef:
              fieldPath: metadata.namespace
        - name: INSTANCE_IP
          valueFrom:
            fieldRef:
              fieldPath: status.podIP
        - name: ISTIO_META_POD_NAME
          valueFrom:
            fieldRef:
              fieldPath: metadata.name
        - name: ISTIO_META_CONFIG_NAMESPACE
          valueFrom:
            fieldRef:
              fieldPath: metadata.namespace
        - name: ISTIO_META_INTERCEPTION_MODE
          value: REDIRECT
        image: docker.io/istio/proxyv2:1.1.1
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        name: istio-proxy
        ports:
        - containerPort: 15090
          name: http-envoy-prom
          protocol: TCP
        readinessProbe:
          failureThreshold: 30
          httpGet:
            path: /healthz/ready
            port: 15020
          initialDelaySeconds: 1
          periodSeconds: 2
        resources:
          limits:
            cpu: "2"
            memory: 128Mi
          requests:
            cpu: 100m
            memory: 128Mi
        securityContext:
          readOnlyRootFilesystem: true
          runAsUser: 1337
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /etc/istio/proxy
          name: istio-envoy
        - mountPath: /etc/certs/
          name: istio-certs
          readOnly: true
      initContainers:
      - args:
        - -p
        - "15001"
        - -u
        - "1337"
        - -m
        - REDIRECT
        - -i
        - '*'
        - -x
        - ""
        - -b
        - ""
        - -d
        - "15020"
        image: docker.io/istio/proxy_init:1.1.1
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        name: istio-init
        resources:
          limits:
            cpu: 100m
            memory: 50Mi
          requests:
            cpu: 10m
            memory: 10Mi
        securityContext:
          capabilities:
            add:
            - NET_ADMIN
      restartPolicy: Never
      volumes:
      - emptyDir:
          medium: Memory
        name: istio-envoy
      - name: istio-certs
        secret:
          optional: true
          secretName: istio.default
status: {}
---
```

Comment: Both of the pods has istio side car injected?

Comment: No, just the second one (`curl`). However, if both have Istio injected it does not work neither.

Comment: If one pod doesn't have Istio it explains why it cannot communicate, Istio versions below 1.1 don't allow connection outside the mesh without "ExternalService" resource.
Do you see the same error when both pods have instio injected?

Comment: Yes, I have the same problem when both Pods have Istio installed. Also, I try it with the most recent Istio version (1.1.1), so if I understand correctly, I don't have to specify any `ExternalService`.

Comment: Hi. I think that istio doesn't allow communication directly between pods but it works between services.

Comment: Can you post output as yaml from `istioctl kube-inject -f curl.yaml`?

Comment: @Crou, Added the output of `istioctl kube-inject -f curl.yaml`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When a pod with an istio side car is started, the follwing things happen

1. an init container changes the iptables rules so that all the outgoing tcp traffic is routed to the sidecar container (istio-proxy) on port 15001 .
2. the containers of the pod are started in parallel (`curl` and `istio-proxy`)

If your curl container is executed before `istio-proxy` listens on port 15001, you get the error.

I started this container with a sleep command, exec-d into the container and the curl worked.

```
$ kubectl apply -f <(istioctl kube-inject -f curl-pod.yaml)

$ k exec -it -n noistio curl -c curl bash
[root@curl /]# curl 172.16.249.198:8000
<xmp>
Hello World


                                       ##         .
                                 ## ## ##        ==
                              ## ## ## ## ##    ===
                           /""""""""""""""""\___/ ===
                      ~~~ {~~ ~~~~ ~~~ ~~~~ ~~ ~ /  ===- ~~~
                           \______ o          _,/
                            \      \       _,'
                             `'--.._\..--''
</xmp>
[root@curl /]#
```

**curl-pod.yaml**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: curl
spec:
  containers:
  - name: curl
    image: centos
    command: ["sleep",  "3600"]
```

Comment: I see, that's exactly what I needed! Thanks @christian. Do you think it's a bug that should be reported as GH Issue to istio/istio? Or is it a known behvior?

Comment: bug sounds to hard. I'd rather say it's a new dependency between the application container and the istio sidecar and that using istio in not as transparent as I would like it to be.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have configured a ingress "Gateway" and after doing that you need to configure a "VirtualService".  See link below for simple example.

https://istio.io/docs/tasks/traffic-management/ingress/#configuring-ingress-using-an-istio-gateway

Once you have deployed the gateway along with the virtual service you should be able to 'curl' you service from **outside** the cluster from an external IP.

But if you want to check for traffic from **INSIDE** the cluster you will need to use istio's mirroring API to mirror the service (pod) from one pod to another pod, and THEN use your command (kubectl apply -f curl.yaml)  to see the traffic.

See link below for mirroring example:

https://istio.io/docs/tasks/traffic-management/mirroring/

hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for answer @dgant1024. If I understand correctly, Gateway is the other way round, if you want to access a Pod/Service (which is inside the Istio cluster), from outside. I need the other way round, I need to access from INSIDE. I checked the mirroring, but it seems to mirror (clone traffic) to another Pod, but I don't need to clone the traffic, but just to access the Pod by its IP address. Like to bypass Istio and be able to communicate directly.

Comment: Do you mean that you want to exec into a container that's located in a pod that has be injected by an istio-proxy ? (ex: kubectl exec -it <podname> -c <container> -n <namespace> -- /bin/bash)

Comment: No, all I'd like to do is to access Pod by its IP address (assuming both Pods are in inside Istio). Like let's say Pod 1 has the IP: `10.0.0.4`, then I'd like to be able to access it from the other Pod by `curl 10.0.0.4`. However it's blocked by the envoy.