# Can I enable pod to pod (via pod IP) communication with Istio?

Tags: kubernetes, istio

Currently running an EKS 1.14 cluster with Istio 1.5.1 and STRICT global mTLS enabled.
I have a StatefulSet that has multiple pods, where one pod is elected leader and the other pods need to communicate with the leader (think rabbitMQ, cassandra, kafka).

Without Istio the communication from podA to podB works without issues by running
`curl -v <podA-IP>` on podB. With Istio however the curl returns

```
curl -v 10.0.20.28:9080
* Rebuilt URL to: 10.0.20.28:9080/
*   Trying 10.0.20.28...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to 10.0.20.28 (10.0.20.28) port 9080 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: 10.0.20.28:9080
> User-Agent: curl/7.52.1
> Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/1.1 502 Bad Gateway
< date: Tue, 07 Apr 2020 14:51:59 GMT
< server: envoy
< content-length: 0
<
* Curl_http_done: called premature == 0
* Connection #0 to host 10.0.20.28 left intact
```

I understand that Istio is geared towards services and ideally we would just always use a service instead of a direct pod to pod connection, but in this case I do need to talk to a specific pod (whose IP is being propagated to the other pods).

Is there a way of contacting another pod by IP that is not:

- Turning Istio off
- Adding a ServiceEntry to treat it as an external service

Thanks in advance!

Edit: 
It seems to work with

```
curl -vvv -H "Host: serviceB" 10.0.20.28:port/page
```

as well, unless that's just

```
curl -v serviceB:port/page
```

in disguise.

Comment: i have same problem but getting 503 instead of 502.

asked the question on istio discussion portal,  https://discuss.istio.io/t/503-between-pod-to-pod-communication-1-5-1/6121

Comment: I found a workaround with a headless service, but unsure how it works.

Answer (score 0):

Istio actually allows Pod to Pod. What you experience may be exactly the same problem I had here: [Istio direct Pod to Pod communication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55455523/istio-direct-pod-to-pod-communication).

You can read the thread, but in short you may be starting your communication before the Envoy sidecar is initialized, so some delaying may solve your issue.

Comment: Thanks! I saw that question, unfortunately I'm running the curl manually after everything is already initialised. I still get the 502 when using the pod IP, while the clusterIP of the service works.